# jfrog artifactory view artifact content without downloading file

Tags: xml, artifactory

Any way to view the artifact content (txt file/xml) from the rest api without having to download it ? 
based on content i will decide if i need to download or not.
I prefer not to use the "property" feature of artifactory, just determine based on file itself.

Comment: do you mean the artifact content type / mime type?

Comment: @greg, did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you refer the "*view the artifact content (txt file/xml)*" same as you have in the Artifactory UI of viewing the content of the file than the answer is yes and no, and I will explain.

When using the REST API, the only option to see the content of the file is by "downloading" it to the end user computer.

Now if you are using `curl`, to run your REST command, you can just run the `curl` like that:

```
curl -u user:password http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/path/to/file/version/file-version.txt
```

This will present the file content without saving it to a file on your computer.

Just to clarify, from a network point of view, the file was transferred to your computer BUT was not saved as a file on your hard drive but only "printed" to your screen.

Does that help?

Comment: Doesn't work for me! Going to the artifact url (image/svg in my case): `https://artifactory-server.com/artifactory/my-local-repo/project-folder/coverage.svg` still forces the browser to download the file, rather than displaying it..